# memory allocation in python

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-memory-allocation

How the memory allocation happens in Python?

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=1
>>> id(a)
2011353552
>>> id(b)
2011353552
>>> b+=1
>>> id(b)
```

Here, id(a) is equal to id(b). When I increment the value of b id(b) changes. Would anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few misconceptions in the question, so I'll just give you some facts and hope it helps:

1. Since number objects are immutable, they may point to the same memory. Specifically a `1` that comes from the source can (but doesn't have to) be always the same object.
2. You don't really increment the value of `b` to be technically correct. You create a new object representing `2` (or get the existing one) and assign it to the `b` variable. It's a new object now.
3. `id()` is for a unique identifier of objects. It doesn't have to relate to memory allocation at all. Currently it does, because `cPython` uses it this way. But as the documentation states:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime.

That's all - nothing more, nothing less. There are multiple optimisations that come into play here, so I wouldn't expect the `id()` to have any kind of reasonable behaviour.

Comment: It is my undestanding that CPython pre-allocates small integers because of how often they're used.

Comment: Yes, up to 256, I believe. But that's cpython specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in python everything is an object and small integer are singleton from `-5` to `256` and  are cached  that is why `id(a) == id(b)` Now when you do `b += 1` you reassign `b` to `b + 1` which is not incrementation. As you can see `a` and `b` point to the same object in your first case but then you reassign `b` it points to different object.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> a is b
True
>>> b += 1
>>> a is b
False
```